# Set SummaryInformation in an msi using Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I am atempting to edit msi files using powershell. I can edit almost every table but the "SummaryInformation" section is not really a table in the same way that the others are.

I can read properties from this information without any problem but I can't set anything.

From the information I have bbeen able to find online I should be able to set it using

```
$SummaryInfo.GetType().InvokeMember("Property", "SetProperty”, $null, $SummaryInfo,@(3,'test'))
```

But when I try this I get a very strange error,

> Exception calling "InvokeMember" with "5" argument(s): **"Property,Pid"**

I only get this error when I specify the "@(3,'test')" array as @(int,string) or-else I get a type mismatch error. This leads me to believe I am close to the correct solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code that I think should work.

```
$MSIPATH = "Path To MSI File"

$windowsInstaller = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer 

$MSIDatabase = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenDatabase", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $windowsInstaller, @($MSIPATH, 1)) 

$SummaryInfo = $MSIDatabase.GetType().InvokeMember(“SummaryInformation”, “GetProperty”,$Null , $MSIDatabase, $Null)

#get the porperty that I want to set
$SummaryInfo.GetType().InvokeMember(“Property”, “GetProperty”, $null, $SummaryInfo, @(3))

#Attempt to set the property this fails
$SummaryInfo.GetType().InvokeMember("Property", "SetProperty”, $null, $SummaryInfo,@(3,'test'))
```

Thanks to mklement0 I have found a solution

The code goes like this

```
$windowsInstaller = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer 
$MSI = $windowsInstaller.OpenDatabase("Path to MSI", 1)

$SummaryInfo = $MSI.SummaryInformation(4)

$SummaryInfo.Property(3) = "Test"
$SummaryInfo.Persist()
$MSI.Commit()
```

Sometimes you just need someone to tell you that you are being dumb.

Comment: Asking naively: Why aren't you invoking the members _directly_ on `$windowsInstaller` and `$SummaryInfo`, why the detour via reflection?

Comment: It's just the way it's implemented. It would make more scene to me of you could go    "$SummaryInfo.InvokeMember("   but you just get back    "Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'InvokeMember'."   Then again I could have missed something.

Comment: By direct invocation I mean `$windowsInstaller.OpenDatabase($MSIPath, 1)`, for instance.

Comment: I would say the main reason is that I did not know that you could do that. It does seem more straightforward.

Comment: I will have a play with this, my googling may be more successful now.

Comment: Please add that answer you found as your own accepted answers for others to find? Some further, possible links: [VBScript SDK samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/windows-installer-scripting-examples) - `WiSumInf.vbs` shows summary stream handling. [Manage Summary Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/manage-summary-information). [Automation Interface Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/automation-interface-reference).

Comment: Found [`WiSumInf.vbs`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/1d363ff4bd17d8e20415b92e2ee989d615cc0d91/Samples/Win7Samples/sysmgmt/msi/scripts/WiSumInf.vbs) in Microsoft's Github repository. And one level up for [the full list of MSI SDK Script samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/1d363ff4bd17d8e20415b92e2ee989d615cc0d91/Samples/Win7Samples/sysmgmt/msi/scripts).

Comment: Thanks! it was from a similar but much less complete vb code sample that I found my solution. This will be helpful in the future.

Comment: Great, I always fish in the [github.com](http://www.github.com) sea to see if I can find samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to mklement0 I have found a solution

I have not been able to do it in the same way I have been editing other tables. But have found a solution by using direct invocation.

The code goes like this

```
$windowsInstaller = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer 
$MSI = $windowsInstaller.OpenDatabase("Path to MSI", 1)

$SummaryInfo = $MSI.SummaryInformation(4)

$SummaryInfo.Property(3) = "Test"
$SummaryInfo.Persist()
$MSI.Commit()
```

EDIT: to correct grammar